# Can't get a value from an URL parameter

Tags: http, web, https, google-api, angular

I'm trying to integrate the Google+ API in my web application which is developed in Angular2 so I can login to the home page using my Google account credentials and without the need to create a new account. I made a clickable html link that has the following `href`

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=**********.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/home`

Once clicking on it, it demands for permission through my google account and when i authorize, it redirect me to the `http://localhost:3000/home?code=4` the problem is that I need the whole code's value so that I can use it to get the `Access Token` but I don't know why the value appeared then it went hidden in less than a second and just keeping the first letter of the code (which is `4` in this case). The problem that if I go back to the previous page of the browser it will appear again.
Any help please? Or Is there any Function in Angular2 that tells the browser to go back to the previous page so I can get the whole code ?

Comment: Don't you think the question title is misleading? The problem seems to be that the query parameter isn't there in the first place, not that you can't get it from the URL.

Comment: Well, maybe it is so general, nevertheless there is a way to get it but i do know how , I made this 

`constructor(public router: Router, params: RouteParams){
        var url = this.router.parent.lastNavigationAttempt;

        console.log(url); 
 }`

I saw that i can get the whole code there but it suffixed with the url, do you know how can I split it alone??

Comment: Sounds like the redirect url doesn't have a route and navigates to the default route. This is why you need `.parent.lastnavigationAttempt`. What about creating a route that matches the redirect URL (or maybe you don't provide the correct redirect URL in the first place which matches the expected route)

Comment: But the the redirect url is a parameter, it is mentioned there in my question as a parameter in the clickable link , and it works well , it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/home` with a prefixed code , the problem is that `google api`  has a behavior that hides the code (maybe for security purposes) so i have to go back to the previous browser page manually, and I think that `lastNavigationAttempt` has the same role, now how can i split the code part alone is my concern .. Sorry I'm new to Angular2 if I'm wrong guide me ?

Comment: I found a way but it is not very practical , however it worked , it is based on skipping the first 16 characters form the previous URL and take the rest of it .. that's a bad way to solve the problem but it is the only way to solve it, as far as i know of course :

`export class LoginPlus {
    constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http, params: RouteParams){
        var url = this.router.parent.lastNavigationAttempt.substring(16);

        console.log(url);`

Any other suggestions i'll appreciate them a lot !